# What are the differences between Virtual and Skill Template

Tags: .net, botframework

I am new to Virtual and Skill Templates.

I want to know the difference between the virtual and skill template, so I can use the template for my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you could not draw direct deference between them.

***`Virtual Template:`***

Virtual template provides you with a set of core foundation capabilities and full control over the end user experience and  combination of  high quality conversational experience as well.

***`Virtual Template Features:`***

1. Provides adaptive card conversational functionality which contains
   button that initially guide the questions even developer can
   customize it.
2. Basic Conversation intents
3. Works out-of-box with Bot Framework Skills and Skill Template

***`Skill Templates:`***

Skill template is the more granular part of your bot which includes different kind of expertise into your bot. Let's say, your bot can fetch user calendar information, your profile information, can sent email and many more. Each  of the item treated as skill.

***`Skill Template Features:`***

1. You can add any skill that you want on your bot
2. Can customize all the skillset

See the picture below which will make you more clear.

[image]

So, your bot may have different kind of functionality like, `Detecting user language`, `Can answer users common question from QnA maker` both it's skill on the other hand virtual template is combination of all skills and basic skeleton of bot.

You could refer

[1.Virtual Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.VirtualAssistantTemplate)

[2. Skill Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-skills-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Hope this would help.